# using replacements with sequelize.literal()

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to use replacements with sequelize.literal() query.

```
router.get('/posts/testapik', function(req, res)
{

    const user_id = req.session.user_id;

    const status ="accept"
  Posts.findAll({include:[{ model: Likes},{ model: Comments},{ model: Users}],
                where:{user_id:{[Op.in]:[sequelize.literal('SELECT `Follows`.receiver_id FROM `follows` AS `Follows` WHERE `Follows`.user_id=? and `Follows`.status=?',{ replacements: [user_id,status], type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })]}}

                })
  .then(users => 
    {

        res.send(users);
  })

});
```

But it returns following error

```
original:
   { Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? and `Follows`.status=?)' at line 1
```

Answer (score -28, accepted):

This Works...
I have used this user_id = '+user_id+'

```
router.get('/posts/testapik', function(req, res)
{

    const user_id = req.session.user_id;

    const status ="accept"
  Posts.findAll({include:[{ model: Likes},{ model: Comments},{ model: Users}],
                where:{user_id:{[Op.in]:[sequelize.literal('(SELECT `Follows`.receiver_id FROM `follows` AS `Follows` WHERE `Follows`.user_id='+user_id+' and `Follows`.status="accept")')]}}

                })
  .then(users => 
    {
        console.log("Posts data Testing =>",users);
        res.send(users);
  })
    .catch((err)=>
    {
        console.error(err)
        res.status(501)
        .send({
                error : "error..... check console log"
              })
    })


});
```

Comment: This can be dangerous because user_id is unprotected and can lead to SQL injections.

Answer (score 10):

For replacements, you have to set the replacements property inside the query object.

```js
router.get("/posts/testapik", function (req, res) {
  const user_id = req.session.user_id;
  const status = "accept";

  Posts.findAll({
    include: [{ model: Likes }, { model: Comments }, { model: Users }],
    replacements: [user_id, status],
    where: {
      user_id: {
        [Op.in]: [
          sequelize.literal(
            "SELECT `Follows`.receiver_id FROM `follows` AS `Follows` WHERE `Follows`.user_id=? and `Follows`.status=?"
          ),
        ],
      },
    },
  }).then((users) => {
    res.send(users);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

For replacements on a raw query you have to write the variable name inside the query with this format: `:userIdReplacement`.

```
const query = '(SELECT `Follows`.receiver_id FROM `follows` AS `Follows` WHERE `Follows`.user_id= :userIdReplacement and `Follows`.status="accept")';

db.sequelize.query(query, { replacements: { userIdReplacement : user_id }});
```

If you have more than one replacement just put it inside the replacements object seperate it by commas.